# R.NET and Microsoft R Open I can't use package xlsx

Tags: r.net

I'm just starting with R.Net and Microsoft R Open.

So far I have been successful with simple tests but I am now trying to convert a .rda file to an Excel spreadsheet.

I have the following code:

```
        REngine engine = REngine.GetInstance();

        engine.Evaluate("dataset<-read.table(file.choose(), header=TRUE, sep = ',')");

        DataFrame dataset = engine.Evaluate("dataset").AsDataFrame();

        engine.Evaluate("dat <- readRDS(file.choose())");

        engine.Evaluate("if(!require(xlsx)) install.packages(\"xlsx\")");
        engine.Evaluate("library(xlsx)");    // <=== where the failure occurs
        engine.Evaluate("write.xlsx(dat, \"../Data/ACS_sub.xlsx\")");
```

and when I try to "get" package xlsx, I get the following error:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'xlsx':
.onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
call: inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...)
error: unable to load shared object 'C:/Users/jim/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/rJava/libs/x64/rJava.dll':
LoadLibrary failure:  %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

"rjava" is installed as is "xlsx" and I used "engine.Evaluate("install_packages()");" to do so.

"openxlsx" is also installed in the same directory and works fine when I try it and was installed the same way.

The install directory is "C:\Users\jim\Documents\R\win-library\3.5\openxlsx\libs\x64" although I am using R Open 3.5.3.  So far I haven't found the way to set the package path to a more appropriate directory.

Java 1.8.0.171 is installed and the environment variable "JAVA_HOME" is correctly set.

My concern is that rjava may be required for other packages so I would like to use this simple test to verify this and I am at a bit of a loss.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working in visual studio, try this: go to project properties, then build and choose there platform target x64